# Self join and get unique records between a date

Tags: sql-server

I have my table and data as follows where I am trying to filter based on period and get results

```
CREATE TABLE testData
(
    Id int,
    period date,
    value decimal(18,2)
)

INSERT INTO testData 
VALUES (1, '2001-08-01', 400), (2, '2001-09-01', 400), (2, '2001-09-01', 300)
```

I have a fiddle which is giving results but not as expected you can check fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/beb4c/5

This is my SQL query

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    [value] - (SELECT TOP 1 b.[value]
               FROM testData b
               WHERE b.period = a.period
               ORDER BY b.id DESC) x
FROM
    testData a
```

Output I am expecting is

```
1  2001-08-01 400 
2  2001-09-01 100
```

Comment: Can you please explain your processing logic a bit more here?  Why does your `2001-09-01` value output `100`?  What happens if there are more than 2 rows per date value?

Comment: When I am having multiple entries on the same data I need to substratc

Comment: But subtract what from what?  If you have `100`, `300` and `800` across the same date, what would the result be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try This

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
      SeqNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Period),
      *
    FROM TestData

)
SELECT
  A.Id,
  A.Period,
  Value = ISNULL(A.Value,0) - ISNULL(Q.Value,0)
  FROM CTE A
    LEFT JOIN(
      SELECT
        B.Id,
        B.period,
        Value = SUM(B.Value)
        FROM CTE B
          WHERE B.SeqNo <> 1
          GROUP BY B.Period,B.Id
     )Q
     ON A.Id = Q.Id
     WHERE A.SeqNo = 1
```

[Fiddle Link Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/beb4c/19)

Comment: Hi Satheesh one small help the original data I am trying is having the decimal filed as varchar when I am casting it is not working can you help me

Comment: Can please you share the details? Like the sample data as well as your query and the error that you are getting

Comment: That's fine since it's not giving you any error. If you are inserting it into a decimal column, then it will automatically cast the data accordingly.

Comment: Thanks one small help if Id is same how can we subtract and show http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/16a8d/3

Comment: Yes Id is same for all the records only period is different

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158853/discussion-between-jayasurya-satheesh-and-chaitanya).